# create a column value if the column value is in the list- python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I want to create a new column called **Playercategory**,

```
Name    Country
Kobe    United States
John    Italy
Charly  Japan
Braven  Japan / United States 
Rocky   Germany / United States
Bran    Lithuania
Nick    United States / Ukraine
Jonas   Nigeria
```

if the player's nationality is 'United States' or United States with **any other country except European country**, then Playercategory=="American"

if the player's nationality is European country or European country with any other country, then Playercategory=="**Europe**" (ex: 'Italy', 'Italy / United States', 'Germany / United States', 'Lithuania / Australia','Belgium')

For all the other players, then Playercategory=="**Non**"

Expected Output:

```
Name    Country                   Playercategory
Kobe    United States             American
John    Italy                     Europe
Charles Japan                     Non
Braven  Japan / United States     American
Rocky   Germany / United States   Europe
Bran    Lithuania                 Europe
Nick    United States / Ukraine   American
Jonas   Nigeria                   Non
```

What I tried:
First I created a list with Europe countries:

```
euroCountries=['Austria', 'Belgium', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia', 'Cyprus', 'Czechia', 'Denmark',
   'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 'Ireland',
   'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Malta', 'Netherlands',
   'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Sweden']
```

i know how to check one condition,like below way,

```
df["PlayerCatagory"] = np.where(df["Country"].isin(euroCountries), "Europe", "Non")
```

But don't know how to concat the above three conditions and create PlayerCategory correctly.

Really appreciate your support!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with test first if match `euroCountries` in [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and then test if match `United States`:

```
m1 = df['Country'].str.contains('|'.join(euroCountries))
m2 = df['Country'].str.contains('United States')
```

Or you can test splitted values with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) or [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and then if at least one match per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df1 = df['Country'].str.split(' / ', expand=True)
m1 = df1.eq('United States').any(axis=1)
m2 = df1.isin(euroCountries).any(axis=1)
```

---

```
df["PlayerCatagory"] = np.select([m1, m2], ['Europe','American'], default='Non')
print (df)
     Name                  Country PlayerCatagory
0    Kobe            United States       American
1    John                    Italy         Europe
2  Charly                    Japan            Non
3  Braven    Japan / United States       American
4   Rocky  Germany / United States         Europe
5    Bran                Lithuania         Europe
6    Nick  United States / Ukraine       American
7   Jonas                  Nigeria            Non
```